# What's wrong with my Joomla installation?

Tags: joomla-2.5

I run Joomla 2.5.28 under Ubuntu 14.04.

I used to have a J 1.5 site, but I upgraded it to 2.5 (the process went well). 
Now, when I want to add a new menu item into Main menu, strange thing happens. I get a wrong path (when I hover my mouse pointer on that newly created menu item) and I see a home page and domain.com address in the browser's address box (if I click on the menu item nevertheless). Normally when I hover my mouse on any menu item, it's like this:

```
mydomain.com/index.php/mypage
```

And what I get is this:

```
mydomain.com/index.php/Feeds/mypage
```

That weird "Feeds" thing... That's what I see in the browser's lower left corner (in Mozilla 42.0) where you see the menu item's link. And even when I try to manually enter "mydomain.com/index.php/Feeds/mypage" in the browser, I get a homepage.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Had to go to Menu Manager in Joomla admin panel and press "Rebuild" button.
Probably Virtuemart did something to Joomla db...

Answer (score 2):

This seems indeed very strange.

One thing - I do not know if you already did it - is the "global checkin" (System->Global Checkin)

or

"Repair database" (you can find that [at least in Joomla 3.x] under Extensions->Manage), there is the tab "database" on the left.
Maybe fixing (upper left corner) will fix your problem.

This could still cause your problem, even though the installation was successful.

Comment: No, unfortunately, it hasn't fixed my problem with Joomla...

Comment: just to clarify this: does this only appear on your main page, or is it also visible on other subpages?